# didExitRegion: 1.5 to 2 minute delay of called when my application is killed or in background in ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ibeacon, estimote

i have to use estimote location beacon,iphone 5s,ios version 10.

didEnterRegion: method also called 30 to 40 seconds delay.

i have to use below code for monitoring ibeacon.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"CFC52BF4-FD33-4569-B4B5-5E9C220514A2"];


CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 identifier:@"Technostacks23"];

region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = YES;
// launch app when display is turned on and inside region
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];

}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



 #pragma mark - CoreLocation Delegate method
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
//local notification fire
}

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
//local notification fire
}
```

please guys tell me how to tackle this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a universal problem on iOS 10.  I have done lots of testing on iOS 10 devices and typically see very fast background detection times.  I would tryrebooting, and uniñstalling other beacon apps besides your own to free up hardware acceleration slots.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can monitor a region at the same time you are ranging. I had this problem on a screen I made where I wanted to show the user if they are in range of the Beacon. I had to stop monitoring until they left the screen, then restart monitoring. If you don't need the events for ranging (how close the user is to the Beacon), I would leave that line off, it isn't necessary to get `-didEnter` and `-didExit` calls. You also shouldn't need `-startUpdatingLocation` either. That is only for active location calls.

Entry events typically fire right away. Exit events do have a 20-30 second delay once you lose signal to the Beacon.

It may be that you are burning up your background run time monitoring, after you run out of time it stops, opening the door for you get monitoring events.

Comment: Thanks @Bill for answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` method in the `didEnterRegion` delegate method so it wont range for beacons when it is not already in the beacons region this will help in power and battery consumption and i believe it would speed up region detection a little bit.
2. Edit your advertising interval of the beacon make it 350ms or less.
3. Check in your iPhone Settings tab for the apps that allow background App Refresh and Location Always and just reverse them to don't allow and make a test see if there would be a difference in detection performance.

But in all cases the 30 - 40 sec delay i find it normal depending on the number of apps that are already processing in the background and running out resources plus it would be even better depending on your app model to start notifying for a region entry after a couple of seconds to make sure also that he is in the region and didn't just pass by so quickly "Im talking for a super market model for instance".

But if this is not your case and you want to detect a region just by passing by i think the fastest you can get will be 15 - 20 sec depending on your device capability, speed, other background processing apps, and the beacons advertising time interval.